# Why is this index blocking my update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have inherited a relatively straightforward query here:

```
UPDATE tblA
SET tblA.Description = 
(SELECT TOP 1 OtherDB.dbo.tblB.Description FROM OtherDB.dbo.tblB WHERE tblA.Code = OtherDB.dbo.tblB.Code)
WHERE tblA.StatusID = 1
```

There are ~140k records in tblA and ~70k in tblB. TblB has no primary keys, but contains a list of codes with descriptions. There is a clustered index on tblB.Code with 2 other columns, also not in this query.

When I run this update, the query never completes, and never updates data. Executing query spins indefinitely. Or possibly not indefinitely, but I let it run for a few minutes and it did not update any records so I cancelled. sp_who2 showed the SPID as Suspended.

Running a package containing this query in an Execute SQL task in SSISDB runs for 15s and then ends with status 6 (ended unexpectedly). Running the package  directly in Visual Studio has a similar issue as the query, the yellow progress "wheel" spins indefinitely when this step is reached.

When I remove one index from tblA, the query executes in under 2s.

The index is on a varchar(50) column, not included this UPDATE query. The column in the index is not part of any keys. In testing, I tried turning off row locks and page locks for the index (and some of the other options), with no differences in the query non-result.

Is the issue comparing across two databases? I've never had such a problem with (what I thought was) a pretty simple update. I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Why does removing the (seemingly) unrelated index allow the the query run to run successfully?

What is the best way to troubleshoot similar issues going forward (other than trial and error, which I've spent a day doing already)?

edit: Additional info, removing the where clause updates all 140k+ records in a few seconds, with the index. But the index is not on the StatusID field.

Comment: have you tried re-indexing the index in question?  It might be fragmented or creating multiple execution plans.

Comment: 1) Get a SQL Trace (with deadlock events enabled), and 2) Monitor ActivityMonitor to look for locks and blocking processes ... between the two, it should tell you exactly what the problem is, or at least nudge you in the right direction. ALSO LOOK AT THE PLAN. It can show you that it probably IS using that index if no other better one exists.

Comment: Also be careful here. You are using top 1 but have no where clause. This means you don't which row you are going get and it could change every time you run this.

Comment: @trapspring I have disabled and rebuilt the index if that is what you are asking. Or maybe I am not understanding.

Comment: @SeanLange I think you mean no ORDER BY... yes, you should always have an explicit ORDER BY when you're using TOP.

Comment: @SeanLange I have rewritten the query with a join too in my testing. Same results. I left that out of the post to keep it a bit shorter.

Comment: @pmbAustin I can't look at the plan because it never completes. I have looked at the estimated plan and did not see anything wild. Someone with more experience might find something there though. But I can try tracing and see what I get.

Comment: Yes you can look at the plan, because you can just select the query in SQL Server Management Studio, and then click the "Estimated Plan" button. It should tell you the indexes it's going to use, and what columns, seek predicates, etc., it's using. Activity Monitor is probably your best bet here though.

Comment: @pmbAustin The index in question is not referenced in the estimated plan. Also updated the post with 1 piece of additional info... Removing the where clause also allows the update (of all 140k rows). HOWEVER, the estimated plan does recommend an index on StatusID, with an impact of 94.9. You may be on to something. I'll look deeper in the trace. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @pmbAustin yes indeed I meant an ORDER BY. Oops...

Comment: Note that the SQL Server Query Optimizer will frequently use an index (especially a clustered one, or a covering index with INCLUDE columns) even if the main column indexed by that index is never referenced in the query... sometimes that gives more efficient results than a table scan. You have to look carefully to notice such things, but I've seen it frequently. Adding a new (proper) index usually fixes things.

Comment: The index issue is the baffling one for me. Is the index clustered? Unique? On a calculated field? The only index on the table? And what triggered you to try dropping this unrelated index? Does it have INCLUDE() columns?

Comment: @LaughingVergil It was literally process of elimination. I tried everything I could think of, ruling out each related piece one by one. The problem started as part of an SSISDB job that reported that odd status of 6. Then I tested in SSIS. Then I started querying in SSMS, testing each part of the query separately and removing lines. Changed it to a join, changed to just a select (which runs). Eventually started dropping indexes just to rule them out, but it fixed the problem. Now to figure out the cause...To answer your questions though, I need to get back to the office to check. :)